# Ui layout disturbs in admin dashboard (magento2 backend)

Tags: magento2, layout, adminhtml, admin-panel

Today when I woke up I see my admin layout seems to be disturbed in the dashboard. Did I by mistake turn off some layout option ? Why it does not seem like the previous layout after the fresh installation ? Is there any solution to fix it?

[image]

I want it to look like in this layout :

[image]

Comment: there were some issue or kind of bug i guess came from hosting , it works fine again itself with proper layout .